# CLI Python. Iterate list of tags: assign, validate, lookup & approve with input()

Tags: python, console

**The Project** I need a "Look Up Table" for *Tags* assigned to *Accounts*. Multiple Tags can be applied to the same Account, but each Tag points to only one Account: EG. [Many-to-One lookup table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65064860/many-to-one-lookup-table-for-taxonomy-mapping). I discovered an SQLLite database would be sufficient.

As a LUT/DB the **database is created once** (just use SQLLite Browser for edits). For this reason I decided to skip implementing the rest of CRUD. Once the user starts the mapping, you have to complete the whole process.

**Problem**

CRUD would have been easier! ... It is easy to **script a series of inputs**. The difficulty happens when you *require each input to have multiple steps*:

- **validate user input**
- **lookup input in DB**
- **user approval**

The common Python input idiom uses `while True` & `break`, but it quickly gets tricky to break from multiple levels of nested `while` loops.

**Solution**

Naively, I wanted a [goto() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18863309/the-equivalent-of-a-goto-in-python), but this is verboten in Python. Suggestions to avoid `goto()` included making [functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18863438/343215), and using exceptions. I found one intereseting [unusual solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37841543/343215), but was unable to adapt it to my needs. I ended up creating functions and choosing a [state-like solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/189645/how-to-break-out-of-multiple-loops/6564670#6564670):

```
import random, re
# Fake tags for loop
til = [{'name' : 'ABC', 'id' : '1'}, {'name' : 'XYZ', 'id' : '2'}, {'name' : 'LMN', 'id' : '3'}]

# TWO HELPER FUNCTIONS
def hf_valid_entry(user_input):
    while True:
        if not user_input: 
            user_input = input("    1. Assign Account#: ")
        if not re.match("\d{4,5}(-\d{2})?", user_input):
            print(f"    2. Bad form: `{user_input}`")
            user_input = None
        else:
            print("    2. Good form.")
            return user_input

def hf_check_acc_num(user_input):
    try:
        # Fake DB Lookup
        record = {'name': 'FOO', 'id' : '1', 'account_number' : '1234'}
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return False
    
    # Simulate bad lookup
    if not random.choice([True, False, False]):
        print("    3. No Record Found.")
        return False
    else:
        print("    3. Found Record.")
        return record

# THE LOOP
for ti in til:
    print("= " * 20)
    print(f"TAG: {ti['name']}") 
    breaker = False
    while True:
        user_input = None
        # VALIDATE ENTRY
        user_input = hf_valid_entry(user_input)          
        print("- " * 20)
        print("Review selection:")
        print(f"TAG NAME: {ti['name']}") 
        # LOOKUP INPUT IN DATABASE  
        record = hf_check_acc_num(user_input)
        if record:
            # PREVIEW
            print(f"Account#: {record['account_number']} - {record['name']}")
            #breaker = False
            response3 = None
            # APPROVE
            while not response3 or response3.lower() not in ('yes', 'y', 'no', 'n'):
                response3 = input("    4. Approve assignment? (y)es, (n)o: ")
                if response3.lower() in ("yes", "y"):
                    breaker = True
                    break
                else:
                    print("5. Not approved!")
                    break
        else:
            pass
            # RETURN TO SAME TAG
        if breaker:
            print("5. Approved!")
            # GO TO NEXT TAG
            break
```

I'm self-taught programmer, and this is a personal project. If you see any redundancies or bad form, I'd appreciate the feedback. I've been making a lot of CLI tools, and so if you have any pseudo-code suggestions for refactoring, that would be great.

Here is the successful test run (enter `1234` to pass validation):

Iterate list of tags:

1. assign account number
2. validate account number
3. Look up account number in 'db'
4. Approve  tag-account number assignment
5. if not approved, try again (same tag)

```
    = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
        1. Assign Account#: 1234
        2. Good form.
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    Review selection:
    TAG ID: 1
    TAG NAME: ABC
        3. No Record Found.              <-- SIMULATE BAD DB LOOKUP
        1. Assign Account#: 1234         <-- RETRY
        2. Good form.
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    Review selection:
    TAG ID: 1
    TAG NAME: ABC                        <-- RETRY WITH SAME TAG
        3. No Record Found.
        1. Assign Account#: 1234
        2. Good form.
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    Review selection:
    TAG ID: 1
    TAG NAME: ABC
        3. Found Record.
    Account#: 1234 - FOO
        4. Approve assignment? (y)es, (n)o: y
    5. Approved!
    = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
    TAG: XYZ                             <-- NEXT TAG
        1. Assign Account#: 1234
        2. Good form.
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    Review selection:
    TAG ID: 2
    TAG NAME: XYZ
        3. Found Record.
    Account#: 1234 - FOO
        4. Approve assignment? (y)es, (n)o: n  <-- REJECT
    5. Not approved!
        1. Assign Account#: 1234           
        2. Good form.
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    Review selection:
    TAG ID: 2
    TAG NAME: XYZ                             <-- SAME TAG  
        3. No Record Found.
        1. Assign Account#: 1234
        2. Good form.
    - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
    Review selection:
    TAG ID: 2
    TAG NAME: XYZ
        3. Found Record.
    Account#: 1234 - FOO
        4. Approve assignment? (y)es, (n)o: y
    5. Approved!
    = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = 
    TAG: LMN                                   <-- MOVE ON TO LAST TAG
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to create a text file with a tag and account number on each line?  The script would load and parse the file, validate the account numbers, and then create the LUT in the database.

Comment: This question is not complete. It's missing, at the least, your imports (`re`, `random`). Please show your complete code, and if _Fake tags for loop_ can be replaced with more of your "real" code, please do that, too.

Comment: I took a stab at sanitizing this program but I can't. It's littered with stubs and faked-out database access. You can have your cake and eat it too: use all-real code, and follow it up with unit tests that perform proper mocking so that a real database is not needed.

Comment: _"Fake tags for loop"_ The real tags are in SQLLite, and since this is about Python `input()`, `ti['name']` is as good as `ti.name`. _"unit tests that perform proper mocking so that a real database is not needed"_ Wow. I don't know how to do that yet. Next week when I have time.